# Network load balancer in single AZ, Application load balancer & ec2 in multiple with cross zone issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an elastic beanstalk application which has an ALB and ec2 instances that can be created in any of the 6 AZ's based on the auto scaling policy.

I then put an NLB in front to create a single static IP which seems to work fine as long as at least 1 ec2 instance exists in the same AZ that the NLB lives. If ec2 instances exist only in other AZ's the health check is timing out and the routing isn't working from the NLB anymore. Is the below a possible configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create Security Group/s that allow traffic between ALB and EC2.

- Create SG for EC2 instance to allow traffic from SG

Comment: Yeah i have. If an ec2 instance exists in us-east-1a then the entire thing works fine. I think the ALB only returns IP addresses to the NLB in AZ's where it has healthy targets, if us-east-1a isn't 1 of those IP addresses then the ALB cannot be hit by the NLB. So i don't think the above is possible